# Google Maps API limitations when searching multiple bounds?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm iterating through an array of bounds

```
boundsarr[1] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(30.567183835166453, -81.72319182746412), new google.maps.LatLng(31.05927189755539, -81.68857520400456));

//boundsarr[2] = ...

//continues...
```

and returning places by keyword for each bounds.  I'm able to get more than 60 places (which is the API limit) because I'm searching places for different bounds but when I have a lot of bounds (e.g 100) places are returned in only 3 or 4 bounds.

It's a [random](http://cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbnails/952699-bigthumbnail.jpg) behavior... I can't figure out why this is happening. My guess is that the API stops processing while places are found.

Please shed some light if you might know the cause!

http://jsfiddle.net/5Czyz/

Comment: Some code please?  Are you checking for errors? Sounds like the calls are returning errors (probably running into a limit on queries).

Comment: @geocodezip sorry, here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/5Czyz/. Im searching a keyword in 2 miles bounds from miami to new york. 259 bounds. As you can see it returns places only in one area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you aren't reporting the status if there is an error, if you add code to report errors, you get lots of annoying alerts, reporting ZERO_RESULTS and OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

http://jsfiddle.net/5Czyz/2/

```
    function callback(results, status) { 
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker(results[i]);
        }
      } else alert("Places request failed: "+status);
    }
```

- the places service is subject to a quota and a rate limit, firing a bunch of queries off like that will have issues.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283826/how-to-to-get-places-e-g-gas-stations-along-route-between-origin-and-destinati), it seems to work at returning the results for an array of bounds, not sure how scaleable it is (your array of bounds is pretty big).

Comment: Thanks! I know how to return results along route with the places service but I'm trying to figure out how to work around the query limit. Perhaps create multiple requests if query limit errors are encountered... I'm not sure.

Comment: My suggestion would be to serialize your requests (as in the example in the question I reference), then if you get a status of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT use setTimeout to delay for some period of time, then retry the request.  Note that the delay needed may vary depending on the load on Google's servers.

Comment: However, I suspect for a route this long (Miami to New York), you won't want to do that, it will take too long and that amount of data will not be useful.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to pay for increased requests per second.