# How to to Get Places (e.g Gas Stations) along Route Between Origin and Destination in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Can you please let me know if it is possible to get list of all places for example Gas Stations along Route Between Origin and Destination in Google Maps API? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/w39qP/) is a link that I am trying to list all Gas Stations or Rest areas ( or any of Google Maps API Supported Place Types)between two points ans based on a Direction supported route.

and this my code so far:

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var haight = new google.maps.LatLng(49.216364,-122.811897);
var oceanBeach = new google.maps.LatLng(50.131446,-119.506838);

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: haight
}
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    calcRoute();
 }

function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
  origin: haight,
  destination: oceanBeach,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
 });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Edited Part:

```
// Make the directions request
  directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

      // Box around the overview path of the first route
      var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
      var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
      drawBoxes(boxes);
    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }

      for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  var bounds = box[i];
  // Perform search over this bounds 
}



  });
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Use the [RouteBoxer](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/routeboxer) to get an array of google.maps.LatLngBounds objects that cover the route.
2. for each of those bounds use the Places library to search for the places.

Note that there are query limits and quotas on the places requests, so for long routes this may not be practical.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_RouteBoxerPlaces.html)

(however, looking at how the results are grouped, it looks like the places service is searching around the center of the bounds, rather than in the bounds, but it might be good enough for your needs).

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var boxpolys = null;
var directions = null;
var routeBoxer = null;
var distance = null; // km
var service = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var boxes = null;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  // Default the map view to the continental U.S.
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -80.5),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 8
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();

  directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });

  // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
  // looking something like  "?marker=3"

  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1).toLowerCase();

    // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "to") {
      document.getElementById('to').value = unescape(value);
    }
    if (argname == "from") {
      document.getElementById('from').value = unescape(value);
    }
    if (argname == "dist") {
      document.getElementById('distance').value = parseFloat(value);
    }
    if (argname == "type") {
      document.getElementById('type').value = unescape(value);
    }
    if (argname == "keyword") {
      document.getElementById('keyword').value = unescape(value);
    }
    if (argname == "name") {
      document.getElementById('name').value = unescape(value);
    }
    if (argname == "submit") {
      route();
    }
  }

}

function route() {
  // Clear any previous route boxes from the map
  clearBoxes();

  // Convert the distance to box around the route from miles to km
  distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1.609344;

  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
    destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }

  // Make the directions request
  directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

      // Box around the overview path of the first route
      var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
      boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
      // alert(boxes.length);
      drawBoxes();
      findPlaces(0);
    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
}

// Draw the array of boxes as polylines on the map
function drawBoxes() {
  boxpolys = new Array(boxes.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxpolys[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: boxes[i],
      fillOpacity: 0,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      map: map
    });
  }
}


function findPlaces(searchIndex) {
  var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
  var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var request = {
    bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
  };
  if (!!type && (type != "")) {
    if (type.indexOf(',') > 0)
      request.types = type.split(',');
    else
      request.types = [type];
  }
  if (!!keyword && (keyword != "")) request.keyword = keyword;
  if (!!name && (name != "")) request.name = name;
  service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds[" + searchIndex + "] returns " + results.length + " results<br>"
      for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
        var marker = createMarker(result);
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds[" + searchIndex + "] returns 0 results<br>&nbsp;status=" + status + "<br>";
    }
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
      searchIndex++;
      if (searchIndex < boxes.length)
        findPlaces(searchIndex);
    } else { // delay 1 second and try again
      setTimeout("findPlaces(" + searchIndex + ")", 1000);
    }

  });
}

// Clear boxes currently on the map
function clearBoxes() {
  if (boxpolys != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxpolys.length; i++) {
      boxpolys[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  boxpolys = null;
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  if (place.icon) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      place.icon, new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      new google.maps.Size(25, 25));
  } else var image = {
    url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
    size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  var request = {
    reference: place.reference
  };
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var contentStr = '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5><p>' + place.formatted_address;
        if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>' + place.formatted_phone_number;
        if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + place.website + '">' + place.website + '</a>';
        contentStr += '<br>' + place.types + '</p>';
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status=" + status + "</h5>";
        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });

  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  if (!place.name) place.name = "result " + gmarkers.length;
  var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1) + "],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</a><br>";
  document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/denissellu/routeboxer@master/src/RouteBoxer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="side_bar" style="width:200px; height: 600px; overflow: auto"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
Box within at least
<input type="text" id="distance" value="3" size="2">miles of the route from
<input type="text" id="from" value="denver" />to
<input type="text" id="to" value="oklahoma city, OK" />
<input type="submit" onclick="route()" />
<br>
<label>type</label>
<input type="text" id="type" value="gas_station" />
<label>keyword</label>
<input type="text" id="keyword" value="" />
<label>name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" />
<div id="towns"></div>
```