# Google Maps Api check if place is on the route

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I made with Google Maps an route between two places. Thats works fine.

But i also have an database with interesting points on different roads in
my country. I like to show them if they are on the generated route. Places who are
not one this route, don't need to be shown.

My database with intereseting points contains latitude and longitude coordinates.

How can i check is they are on my route? There are approximately 30 or 40 interesting
point in my database.

```
// set request
var request = {
    origin: initialLocation,
    destination: destination,               
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

 // make route
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      // set route
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);


    }

});
```

**UPDATE:**
Build new function "isLocationOnEdge". But the check runs the markers when they are not on the road:

```
// get flitsers on the route
function getFlitsersOnRoute(){

    // set request
    var request = {
        origin: current_location,
        destination: $('#gegevens').html(),               
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };  

    // make route
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

        // isLocationOnEdge
        var isLocationOnEdge = google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge;      
        var coords = response.routes[0].overview_path;
        var image = base_url+'external/afbeeldingen/google_markers/flitser.png';

        // get flitsers
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            url: base_url+"advies/get/9",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);    

                // loop trough flitsers
                $.each(result.flitsers.m, function(i, item) {

                    // latitude longitude
                    var latlng = item["@attributes"].gps.split(",");

                    // make google latlng
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0],latlng[1]);                     

                    if (myLatlng,coords)
                    {
                        // set and define the marker 
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                            size: new google.maps.Size(15, 15),
                            icon: image,
                            title: 'Flitser'
                        });     
                    }

                });
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Add the interesting places to an array. Then for each coord in the route polyline, check it against the array of interesting places.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to to Get Places (e.g Gas Stations) along Route Between Origin and Destination in Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283826/how-to-to-get-places-e-g-gas-stations-along-route-between-origin-and-destinati), use your database instead of the places API.

Comment: Thanks for comments! The answer below is an example of your answers i guess.

Comment: Where are you using `isLocationOnEdge`? How does your program know when to place a marker on the line?

Comment: new google.maps.Marker creates the marker. The var is only to store the marker in a later stadium.

Answer (score 3):

isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)

To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or near the edge of a polygon, pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and optionally a tolerance value in degrees to google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(). The function returns true if the distance between the point and the closest point on the line or edge falls within the specified tolerance. The default tolerance value is 10-9 degrees.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Answer (score 1):

Include the geometry library in your Google Maps API request:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&`**`libraries=geometry`**`&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE`

Pseudo-code:

```
// Make isLocationOnEdge easier to access
var isLocationOnEdge = google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge;

for (var i = 0; i < interestingPlaces.length; i++) {
    if (isLocationOnEdge(interestingPlaces[i],
                         response.routes[0].overview_path))
        {
            // Do something with interestingPlaces[i]
        }
}
```

[Google maps documentation for `isLocationOnEdge()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

Comment: Thank your for the comment! This is what i search for. I only get one error rightnow. Did it like:      myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0],latlng[1]);     
     
if (isLocationOnEdge(myLatlng,response.routes[0].overview_path))
{
      
}  error: "TypeError: b.get is not a function"

Comment: It's hard to say without more code, but it looks like `new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0], latlng[1])` is your problem. It appears that you are sending two **`latLng`s** to create a new `latLng`. The API requires two **numbers**. So `google.maps.LatLng(Number, Number)` should be better.

Comment: I added some code in my question. My error is solved but the script doesn't work yet.