# How can I remove old markers from direction A to B

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pYy4B/) to add markers on my direction A to B. How can I remove "old" markers, when I add new start and end points.
I try to change `gmarkers[j].setMap(null);` but not working.

```
for (var j=0; j< gmarkers.length; j++) {
      if (boxes[i].contains(gmarkers[j].getPosition()))
          gmarkers[j].setMap(map);
  }
```

[fiddle/original code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912796/google-api-v3-show-nearby-markers-on-customer-road)

Comment: What are the markers for? I see that you verify that your boxes do contain them, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. You have a clearBoxes function. You can [use it to clear the markers](http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/nwm69tgh/) as well.

```
function clearBoxes() {
  if (boxpolys != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxpolys.length; i++) {
      boxpolys[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  for (var j=0; j< gmarkers.length; j++) {
      gmarkers[j].setMap(null);
  }
  boxpolys = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the setVisible function:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(10, -10), 
map: map
}); 

marker.setVisible(false);
```

in your case:

```
for (var j=0, m; m = gmarkers[j]; j++)
{
    m.setVisible(false);
}
```

With .setMap() you kind of loose the reference; setVisible() toggles the marker

best

M

Comment: This answer works as well. You should add that this path requires the original code to be modified to use setVisible(true) when re-enabling the markers.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the markers, do this (set their map property to null):

```
for (var i=0;i<gmarkers.length;i++){
  gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYy4B/1/)

Comment: Thank you for this and thanks for previous help, I appreciate it!