# How can I see the nearby places between two locations in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I see the nearby places between two location.

For example:

From:İstanbul
To:Ankara

I want to see cafes on this route.

[Cafes along route image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNLZw.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to to Get Places (e.g Gas Stations) along Route Between Origin and Destination in Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283826/how-to-to-get-places-e-g-gas-stations-along-route-between-origin-and-destinati) (search for cafes rather than gas stations.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest having a look at [RouteBoxer](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/routeboxer) library. This library allows to  generate a set of LatLngBounds objects that are guaranteed to contain every point within a given route. After that you can use places search with a set of LatLngBounds to find cafes within given bounds.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Answer (score -1):

For android after select for example driving, at top you can change "Your Location" to anywhere else.
or you can use "[Measure distance](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1628031?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)" to calculate direct distance between places.