# How will i get the details of the nearby restaurants on my route in android?

Tags: android, google-places-api, routeboxer

I want to draw path between two points(Source and destination) and simultaneously i want to show restaurants between my route (path).

I hear about RouteBoxer but i am not getting how to use it

I have try following code
[this](https://github.com/aryoxp/RouteBoxer)

Comment: what have your tried so far? Show us some Code and where you're struggling.

Comment: I have read this documents:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283826/how-to-to-get-places-e-g-gas-stations-along-route-between-origin-and-destinati

https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2010/05/search-along-route-made-easy-with.html



I also tried this code but its not working

https://github.com/aryoxp/RouteBoxer